# PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to do a `LEFT JOIN FETCH` to load a lazy loaded some data, but I am getting the following error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 726
```

I have searched everywhere online to see what I am doing incorrectly, but I don't see what I am doing differently (other than my id not being a primitive type).

Here is what I have

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "foo_definition")
public class FooDefinition implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private FooId fooId;
  ...
}
```

Key

```
@Embeddable
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FooId implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "fooId")
  private String id;

}
```

Repo

```
@Repository
public interface FooDefinitionRepository extends CrudRepository<FooDefinition, FooId> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM FooDefinition c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.bundles WHERE c.fooId = :fooId")
    FooDefinition findByIdAndFetchBundlesEagerly(@Param("fooId") FooId fooId);
}
```

DB

```
CREATE TABLE foo_definition (
    foo_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

I have also tried message around with the query and the passed in type, e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM FooDefinition c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.bundles WHERE c.fooId.id = :fooId")
FooDefinition findByIdAndFetchBundlesEagerly(@Param("fooId") FooId fooId);

@Query("SELECT c FROM FooDefinition c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.bundles WHERE c.fooId.id = :fooId")
FooDefinition findByIdAndFetchBundlesEagerly(@Param("fooId") String fooId);

@Query("SELECT c FROM FooDefinition c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.bundles WHERE c.fooId = :fooId")
FooDefinition findByIdAndFetchBundlesEagerly(@Param("fooId") String fooId);
```

But none of these work as well (different errors)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to do two things:

- replaced the complex key type of `FooId` with just a `String`
- replaced my `JoinTable` mapping with `JoinColumn`, for my `OneToMany` relation of some fields in my `FooDefinition` class